# Is there any continuous function in the Sobolev space $\mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but not in $\mathcal{H}^{d/2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces

Is there any continuous (and possibly bounded) function in the Sobolev space $\mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but not in $\mathcal{H}^{d/2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Where $k<d/2$ and $\mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)=\mathcal{W}^{k,2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Since it seems quite standard to assume the Sobolev space with the smoothness bigger than $d/2$ because of the embedding result:
if $k>d/2$, then $\mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is continuously embedded in the bounded continuous functions $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

However, when the dimension $d$ is large and one only needs continuity, it is not convenient to assume the smoothness bigger than $d/2$. But also I need the function to be in $\mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with some $k$ out of other reasons ($k<d/2$).

In other words, is it possible to prove

$C_b(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap \mathcal{H}^k(\mathbb{R}^d) \not\subseteq \mathcal{H}^{d/2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ where $k<d/2$?

Any comments/references appreciated!
(In the best case, I would like to see such function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest examples will have $d = 4$, $d/2 = 2$, and $k=1$, so the question boils down to showing  $$C_b(\mathbb R^4) \cap H^1(\mathbb R^4) \not\subseteq H^2(\mathbb R^4).$$

What you need is a function whose first order partial derivatives belong to $L^2$ but whose second order partial derivatives do not. You could try something like
$$ \phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = |x_1|^{2/3}$$
which is locally integrable and deal with the behavior at $\infty$ using a cutoff function $\eta$ with the property that $0 \le \eta \le 1$, $\eta(x) = 1$ for all $|x| \le 1$, and $\eta(x) = 0$ for all $|x| > 2$.

The function $f(x) = \phi(x) \eta(x)$ should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! It's a simple and nice example.